# gulp-concat only concatenating a couple (and a half) JS files

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I have been using gulp-concat to mix up my javascript files into one (duh) but for some reason, and has only started happening today, it is concatenating seven and a half out of 15+ files.

Nothing has changed to the gulpfile.

**gulpfile**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

// SCSS
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./build_assets/scss/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

//JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./build_assets/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
});


//Default
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('build_assets/js/**', function(event) {
        gulp.run('scripts');
    })
    gulp.watch('build_assets/scss/**', function(event) {
        gulp.run('sass');
    })

})
```

**Gulp output**

```
[16:16:29] Starting 'scripts'...
[16:16:29] Finished 'scripts' after 110 ms
```

My SCSS files are being converted just fine and there is no error being thrown by Gulp.

**Note** Probably irrelevant but I noticed an `SyntaxError: illegal character �` in my console. I can't find it anywhere in my JS files.

Comment: It may be a good idea to open the file that is concatenated only in half in a text editor that can display non-printable characters and check if there isn't any strange character there.

Comment: @PawełChorążyk - I did in Vim. Nothing there. I rebooted Vagrant and it seems to be working now though. strange.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the issue was but I rebooted the Vagrant box and it seems to be working now.